# Redirect from '/' in React-Router

Tags: react-router

I trying setup redirect from "/account" to "/account/signIn"

```
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from="/account" to="/account/signIn" />
      <Route path="/account/signIn" component={() => <div>signIn</div>} />
      <Route path="/account/signUp" component={() => <div>signUp</div>} />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
```

When i go to http://localhost:3000/account/signUp i redirecting to http://localhost:3000/account/signIn.
This problem is fixed in this way:

```
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path="/account" render={() => <Redirect to="/account/signIn" />} />
    <Route path="/account/signIn" component={() => <div>signIn</div>} />
    <Route path="/account/signUp" component={() => <div>signUp</div>} />
  </Layout>
```

But i think that is not best way, because i have a question this is bug or normal behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `from` on `<Redirect>` matches loosely by default. As you have it, it will match anything that starts with /account, which includes your /account/signIn and /account/signUp paths.

Inside of Switch, it's actually reading the props of its children directly and doesn't distinguish the type of component. So, [you can use `exact` and `strict`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L42) like you can on a Route.

Therefore, this should work for you:

```
<Layout>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/account" to="/account/signIn" />
    <Route path="/account/signIn" component={() => <div>signIn</div>} />
    <Route path="/account/signUp" component={() => <div>signUp</div>} />
  </Switch>
</Layout>
```